# Equivalent of setResizeWeight() on SplitPane in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, splitpane

In Swing, we could use [`setResizeWeight()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html#setResizeWeight%28double%29) on JSplitPane to determine what portion of the SplitPane received the available space. Is there an equivalent method in JavaFX 2.2? I can only find the `setDividerPosition()` method which doesn't really do what I want (granted I could call it manually each time the size changes, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.)

I could also call `setResizableWithParent(false)`, but again that doesn't really provide the sort of control I'm after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While going through the API for SplitPane, I found this static function - [setResizableWithParent(root, Boolean.FALSE)](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/SplitPane.html#setResizableWithParent%28javafx.scene.Node,%20java.lang.Boolean%29) which provides similar functionality as `setResizeWeight()` in JSplitPane.

```
    SplitPane sp = new SplitPane();
    final StackPane sp1 = new StackPane();
    sp1.getChildren().add(new Button("Button One"));
    final StackPane sp2 = new StackPane();
    sp2.getChildren().add(new Button("Button Two"));
    final StackPane sp3 = new StackPane();
    sp3.getChildren().add(new Button("Button Three"));
    sp.getItems().addAll(sp1, sp2, sp3);
    sp.setDividerPositions(0.3f, 0.6f, 0.9f);

    SplitPane.setResizableWithParent(sp1, Boolean.FALSE);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(sp, 300, 200));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Welcome to JavaFX!"); 
    primaryStage.sizeToScene(); 
    primaryStage.show();
```

`setResizableWithParent` can mimic the values of `setResizeWeight(0)` and `setResizeWeight(1)` but absolutely nothing in between. Basically, the node can either be free-flowing or fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - but yup, I'm after something with a resize weight of something in between! That's where my difficulty lies it seems...

Comment: `primaryStage.titleProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty().asString().concat(":").concat(sc.heightProperty().asString()));
        DoubleBinding wid=scene.widthProperty().add(0);`                 Tried binding this with `sp1.widthProperty()` but there is no such function in the API.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it helped me and yes, a setResizeWeight would be great.